# "Missing required 57x57 icon" for iOS on PhoneGap Build

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I'm using PhoneGap Build and I have all the necessary icons defined in config.xml

```
<icon src="icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="ios/icon57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="ios/icon72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="ios/icon114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="ios/icon120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="ios/icon144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="ios/icon152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
```

but when publishing the app I get the error message:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not
>   contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod touch of exactly '57x57' pixels, in .png
>   fomat for iOS versions < 7.0."

A few month ago I had similar issues with icons. I spent lots of time trying adding/removing some, and I think I basically ended removing all icons except the 57x57 one. That was fine but the icon didn't look that nice on retina displays. I hoped that problem would have been fixed by now.

FYI I was previously using PhoneGap 2.9 and this time it's 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply removing the default icon `<icon src="icon.png" width="57" height="57" />` from the config.xml file did the trick for some reason.

It seems quite a lot of people are having troubles with icons too, and that solution was mentioned a few times (for different PhoneGap versions) on the community.phonegap.com website, like [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/submit_app_to_appstore_icon_dimensions_57_x_57_dont_meet_the_requirements#reply_12165801). It's also said to define the iOS icons before any other in the config.xml file (which was already the case for me). I tried just putting the default icon after the iOS specific ones but I still got the same error.